# Eclipse Sirius - I want to convert my existing code into model

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-sirius

I find meta-modeling very interesting, so I installed Sirius and am trying to convert an already existing application into modules that I can represent in Sirius.

However, I don't know where to start. When I installed the plugin, it does nothing, and I think I need to install additional plugins i.e. UML Designer to do what I need.

I need some articles/tutorial that tells the steps to use sirius from scratch. The articles that I've read already has sample data and I need a from scratch example.

Also, can somebody create an eclipse-sirius tag in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sirius will help you to create your own graphical modeling tool. UML Designer is a modeling tool created with Sirius and dedicated to the UML standard.

Maybe you could try this Sirius [tutorial](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Sirius/Tutorials/4MinTutorial).

The Sirius community is more active on the Eclipse.org [forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=262).